# Error while executing SVN checkin command

Tags: svn

I am getting following error while executing the SVN checkin command

```
svn -ci -m "Adding images and data to resource bundle" ./Images/*.* ./Data/*.*
```

**Error:-** 
svn: Non-numeric change argument (i) given to -c

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be

```
svn ci ... etc ...
```

(no minus needed).  "check in" is an alias for the commit command - it's not an option.

Answer (score 2):

The correct command is svn ci, not svn -ci